# How to call prompt on windows desktop app using js?

Tags: javascript, windows, vbscript, desktop-application, prompt

I have js code, which should be executed on windows (not in browser).
I need to show prompt with `message`, two `buttons`, `default` answer, and user `input field`.

I have tried to find any information here on stackoverflow, in google, in official documnts, but it seems I do that not such good as it is needed. Can you give me a link or just write the code line I need?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can implement native Windows App with Javascript. But have a look at [electron](https://electron.atom.io/) or [appjs](http://appjs.com/).

Comment: @zwif, it is for my own use, and it is very simple. (but it should works on windows desktop, not in browser). The one problem I have is `prompt`

Comment: You might want to use JScript from Microsoft instead of JavaScript. JScript is often confused with JavaScript and can be executed on Windows if group policies don't restrict its execution. Zwif is right, JavaScript cannot be executed on Windows. Maybe this link is helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106806/how-to-show-a-popup-without-a-browser. You might take a look at the ActiveXObject.

Comment: More information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript#Comparison_to_JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

documentation link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f(VS.85).aspx
Thank you all commentors for help :)